# Hide Form when submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have the following function:

```
var form = $('#review-contact-form');
form.submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var form_status = $('<div class="form_status center"></div>');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        data: form.serialize(),
        beforeSend: function(){
            form.prepend(
                form_status
                    .html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Sending...</p>')
                    .fadeIn()
            );
        }
    }).done(function(data){
        form_status
            .html('<p class="text-success">Thanks!</p>')
            .delay(3000)
            .fadeOut();
    });
});
```

Is there a way to hide the form when mail is sent?

Comment: Add `form.hide();` as the first line in the `done` function, above `form_status`.

Comment: You can use `form.hide()`. But you'll need to put the `form_status` DIV somewhere else then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fadeOut()` on the `form` too in the `done` promise:

```
  var form = $('#review-contact-form');
  form.submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var form_status = $('<div class="form_status center"></div>');
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: $(this).attr('action'),
      data: form.serialize(),
      beforeSend: function() {
        form.prepend(
          form_status
          .html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Sending...</p>')
          .fadeIn()
        );
      }
    }).done(function(data) {
      form.fadeOut();
      form_status
        .html('<p class="text-success">Thanks!</p>')
        .delay(3000)
        .fadeOut();
    });
  });
```

Also, if you have the `.form_status` and `.text-success` elements inside the form move it outside of it, otherwise you won't be able to see the message when the form submit is done.

Comment: This will also hide the `Thanks!` message, since it's inside `form`.

Comment: @Barmar, have you read the message under the code from my answer?

Comment: Oops. didn't see that, sorry

Comment: @user1818326, it should, unless you have another problem. Check the console for errors. What do you see? What not working means? Please describe your problem so I can help you.

Comment: @user1818326 Thanks message appear and hide after few seconds and is outside the form

Comment: @user1818326, So it works? I don't understand. It supposed to happen that way because you have the 3 seconds delay `.delay(3000)` before the `fadeOut()` of the `.text-success`.

Comment: Sorry, Thanks, should stay visible, I have removed .delay(3000) but disappeared in less then a second :(

Comment: @user1818326, That's happening because you use `.fadeOut()`. If is hidden and you want to show it and stay there you need to use `.fadeIn()`. like `form_status.html('<p class="text-success">Thanks!</p>').fadeIn();`

Comment: @user1818326, Also, does the form hides after the email is sent? Because that was your original question. If you have another problem, maybe you should post another question so people can help you. If you had enough reputation I would've invited you to a chat conversation to help you out, but I can't because of your low reputation. Sorry, but we can't transform this comments into a chat because of the rules. But I think I can post one or two comments more and try and help you out.

Comment: @user1818326, If you think my answer helped you solve your problem please don't forget to accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`form.hide();` after your `form_status` in `done` function.

NOTE: I added this as answer because I cannot add comments

Comment: That will also hide the `Thanks!` message, since it's prepended to `form`.

Comment: You are right, I agree with your comment, he needs to put that `div` somewhere else

Comment: Thanks disappear also if is outside the form!